# Jax RS Authorization

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, restlet

I have an existing code at a class which is extended from `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`

```
...
Context childContext = component.getContext().createChildContext();
JaxRsApplication application = new JaxRsApplication(childContext);
application.add(this);
application.setStatusService(new ErrorStatusService());
childContext.getAttributes().put("My Server", this);
...

ChallengeAuthenticator challengeGuard = new ChallengeAuthenticator(null, ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "REST API Realm");
//Create in-memory users with roles
MemoryRealm realm = new MemoryRealm();
User user = new User("user", "user");
realm.getUsers().add(user);
realm.map(user, Role.get(null, "user"));
User owner = new User("admin", "admin");
realm.getUsers().add(owner);
realm.map(owner, Role.get(null, "admin"));
//Attach verifier to check authentication and enroler to determine roles
challengeGuard.setVerifier(realm.getVerifier());
challengeGuard.setEnroler(realm.getEnroler());
challengeGuard.setNext(application);
// Attach the application with HTTP basic authentication security
component.getDefaultHost().attach(challengeGuard);
```

I don't have a web.xml at my code. I would like to add authorization to my code. This: https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/security/authorization does not apply to me since I don't have restlet resources.

How can I implement jax rs authorization into my code?

**EDIT 1:** Existing code uses restlet JAX-RS extension: https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.2/extensions/jaxrs

I've tried that at my jax-rs resource class:

```
@GET
@Path("/")
public String getStatus() {
  if (!securityContext.isUserInRole("admin")) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
  }
  ...
}
```

However, it throws 403 even I log in with `admin` user.

**EDIT 2:**

When I check here: https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.2/extensions/jaxrs There is a piece of code:

```
this.setRoleChecker(...); // if needed
```

This may solve my issue but I don't know how to set a role checker.

**PS:** I use jersey 1.9 and restlet 2.2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could make it work like that:

Application class:

```
...
application.setRoles(getRoles(application));
... 
public static List<Role> getRoles(JaxRsApplication application) {
  List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
  for (AuthorizationRoleEnum authorizationRole : AuthorizationRoleEnum.values()) {
      roles.add(new Role(application, authorizationRole.toString()));
  }
  return roles;
}
...
```

Authorization enum:

```
public enum AuthorizationRoleEnum {
  USER("user"),
  ADMIN("admin");

  private final String value;

  AuthorizationRoleEnum(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return value;
  }

}
```

At my resource classes:

```
...
@Context
SecurityContext securityContext;
...
allowOnlyAdmin(securityContext);
...
public void allowOnlyAdmin(SecurityContext securityContext) {
  if (securityContext.getAuthenticationScheme() != null
    && !securityContext.isUserInRole(AuthorizationRoleEnum.ADMIN.toString())) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN)
      .entity("User does not have required " + AuthorizationRoleEnum.ADMIN + " role!").build());
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear (at least to me :-) ) what you are trying to achieve.
If you have a class which is a subclass of javax.ws.rs.core.Application, you should be able to simply add @RolesAllowed("user") as an annotation to your resource classes, as shown in https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html

```
@Path("/")
@PermitAll
public class Resource {
    @RolesAllowed("user")
    @GET
    public String get() { return "GET"; }

    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    @POST
    public String post(String content) { return content; }

    @Path("sub")
    public SubResource getSubResource() {
        return new SubResource();
    }
}
```

Accessing that resource should prompt you for your credentials. If that doesn't work, then you need to provide a small code sample, which compiles and doesn't do what you want it to do. Then it's easier to see where the problem is and what needs to be done to make it work

Comment: I've edited my question. Answer could be very simple but I couldn't find a way to make it work. I define the roles via restlet (it uses jax-rs extension) however it seems that it doesn't being recognized by jax-rs security context.

Comment: if it gives you a 403 error, then it means that the authentication is working :-) You just need to add the user to the correct group. This is done in the application server security configuration. Did you set a breakpoint at the first line in getStatus() to see if it actually gets there?

Comment: Yes, authentication works. However authorization is not :) It really goes there but cannot get user's role to check. Everybody gets 403. It seems that  jersey context doesn't recognize restlet user? However it isn't like that at here: http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/SecurityContext-with-JaxRS-Extension-td3396753.html

Comment: What type of application server are you using? The mapping of users to roles is done in the application server.

Comment: I just use `component.start();` to start the application. I don't have a web.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your `RoleChecker` [using this interface](https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/1.1/all/ext/org/restlet/ext/jaxrs/RoleChecker.html).
As the doc says:

> Because the Restlet API does not support its own mechanism for role checks (as e.g. the Servlet API), you must use this inteface if you need role checks in a JAX-RS application.
>   This interface is used to check, if a user is in a role. Implementations must be thread save.

so as an example of implementation you can do smth like this:

```
  public class MyRoleChecker implements RoleChecker {
    public boolean isInRole(Principal principal, String role) {
      return principal.getRole().equals(role);
    } 
  }
```

---

Edited:
On the other hand as you use the new API, you need to implement `SecurityContext` and inject it using @Context in your resource methods. 
Then you fetch roles list from the storage by username. The storage implementation is up to you. Please refer to this [example](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-security-context-injax-rs)

```
    @Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthFilterWithCustomSecurityContext implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String authHeaderVal = requestContext.getHeaderString("Auth-Token");
        String subject = validateToken(authHeaderVal); //execute custom authentication
        if (subject!=null) {
            final SecurityContext securityContext = requestContext.getSecurityContext();
            requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
                        @Override
                        public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                            return new Principal() {
                                @Override
                                public String getName() {
                                    return subject;
                                }
                            };
                        }
                        @Override
                        public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
                            List<Role> roles = findUserRoles(subject);
                            return roles.contains(role);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public boolean isSecure() {
                            return uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString().startsWith("https");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
                            return "Token-Based-Auth-Scheme";
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems reasonable. However is there any example about how to implement it?

Comment: @kamaci I edited my answer adding an example of implementation.

Comment: I use `org.restlet.ext.jaxrs` version 2.2.3 but seems it doesn't have an interface named as `RoleChecker`?

Comment: On the other hand `Principal` class does not have a `getRole()` method: `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html`

Comment: Right, that's old API, and you use the new one.

Comment: Alsom seems that restlet documentation is wrong: https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.2/extensions/jaxrs there is no way to for a call `setRoleChecker()`.

Comment: @kamaci it's just obsolete. I edited my answer, please have a look.

Comment: Is it `org.restlet.security.User`? It doesn't have `getRole()` method too. On the other hand I use `jersey 1.9`.

Comment: @kamaci   I edited another way. Hope now it makes sense.

Comment: Does jersey 1.9 has `Priority`? On the other hand from which package is `User`?

Comment: @kamaci it's still java.security.Principal used.

Comment: OK. But it cannot find the `Priority` annotation and finds `ContainerRequestFilter` at `com.sun.jersey.spi.container`. It should be `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter` however there is no container package at jersey 1.9.

Comment: Lastly, I can access to header. However your example uses a token based authentication and accesses to that token. However, I don't have such a header at my example.